# breadth first search optimisation in python

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-algorithm, breadth-first-search

I was solving a problem related to breadth first search. I solved the problem but my solution took the longest time to solve (0.12 as compared to 0.01 and 0.02 done by others). The question is a simple BFS on a graph.

Here is how I have implemented BFS:

```
def bfs1(g, s):
    parent = {s: None}
    level = {s: 0}
    frontier = [s]
    ctr = 1
    while frontier:
            next = []
            for i in frontier:
                for j in g[i]:
                    if j not in parent:
                        parent[j] = i
                        level[j] = ctr
                        next.append(j)
            frontier = next
            ctr += 1
    return level
```

Here **g** and **s** are adjacency list (dict in case of python) and starting Node respectively.

I learned this approach from MIT algorithms course.

[Here](http://www.spoj.com/problems/NAKANJ/) is the problem which I was solving.

Below is the complete solution which I submitted

```
Here d is the graph which I pre-generated 


d={'f1': ['d2', 'e3', 'h2', 'g3'], 'f2': ['d1', 'd3', 'e4', 'h1', 'h3', 'g4'], 'f3': ['d2', 'd4', 'e1', 'e5', 'h2', 'h4', 'g1', 'g5'], 'f4': ['d3', 'd5', 'e2', 'e6', 'h3', 'h5', 'g2', 'g6'], 'd8': ['b7', 'c6', 'f7', 'e6'], 'f6': ['d5', 'd7', 'e4', 'e8', 'h5', 'h7', 'g4', 'g8'], 'f7': ['d6', 'd8', 'e5', 'h6', 'h8', 'g5'], 'f8': ['d7', 'e6', 'h7', 'g6'], 'h3': ['f2', 'f4', 'g1', 'g5'], 'h1': ['f2', 'g3'], 'h6': ['f5', 'f7', 'g4', 'g8'], 'h7': ['f6', 'f8', 'g5'], 'h4': ['f3', 'f5', 'g2', 'g6'], 'h5': ['f4', 'f6', 'g3', 'g7'], 'b4': ['a2', 'a6', 'd3', 'd5', 'c2', 'c6'], 'b5': ['a3', 'a7', 'd4', 'd6', 'c3', 'c7'], 'b6': ['a4', 'a8', 'd5', 'd7', 'c4', 'c8'], 'b7': ['a5', 'd6', 'd8', 'c5'], 'b1': ['a3', 'd2', 'c3'], 'b2': ['a4', 'd1', 'd3', 'c4'], 'b3': ['a1', 'a5', 'd2', 'd4', 'c1', 'c5'], 'd6': ['b5', 'b7', 'c4', 'c8', 'f5', 'f7', 'e4', 'e8'], 'd7': ['b6', 'b8', 'c5', 'f6', 'f8', 'e5'], 'd4': ['b3', 'b5', 'c2', 'c6', 'f3', 'f5', 'e2', 'e6'], 'd5': ['b4', 'b6', 'c3', 'c7', 'f4', 'f6', 'e3', 'e7'], 'b8': ['a6', 'd7', 'c6'], 'd3': ['b2', 'b4', 'c1', 'c5', 'f2', 'f4', 'e1', 'e5'], 'd1': ['b2', 'c3', 'f2', 'e3'], 'e1': ['c2', 'd3', 'g2', 'f3'], 'f5': ['d4', 'd6', 'e3', 'e7', 'h4', 'h6', 'g3', 'g7'], 'd2': ['b1', 'b3', 'c4', 'f1', 'f3', 'e4'], 'e5': ['c4', 'c6', 'd3', 'd7', 'g4', 'g6', 'f3', 'f7'], 'h2': ['f1', 'f3', 'g4'], 'e3': ['c2', 'c4', 'd1', 'd5', 'g2', 'g4', 'f1', 'f5'], 'h8': ['f7', 'g6'], 'e2': ['c1', 'c3', 'd4', 'g1', 'g3', 'f4'], 'g7': ['e6', 'e8', 'f5', 'h5'], 'g6': ['e5', 'e7', 'f4', 'f8', 'h4', 'h8'], 'g5': ['e4', 'e6', 'f3', 'f7', 'h3', 'h7'], 'g4': ['e3', 'e5', 'f2', 'f6', 'h2', 'h6'], 'g3': ['e2', 'e4', 'f1', 'f5', 'h1', 'h5'], 'g2': ['e1', 'e3', 'f4', 'h4'], 'g1': ['e2', 'f3', 'h3'], 'e4': ['c3', 'c5', 'd2', 'd6', 'g3', 'g5', 'f2', 'f6'], 'g8': ['e7', 'f6', 'h6'], 'a1': ['c2', 'b3'], 'a3': ['c2', 'c4', 'b1', 'b5'], 'a2': ['c1', 'c3', 'b4'], 'a5': ['c4', 'c6', 'b3', 'b7'], 'a4': ['c3', 'c5', 'b2', 'b6'], 'a7': ['c6', 'c8', 'b5'], 'a6': ['c5', 'c7', 'b4', 'b8'], 'c3': ['a2', 'a4', 'b1', 'b5', 'e2', 'e4', 'd1', 'd5'], 'c2': ['a1', 'a3', 'b4', 'e1', 'e3', 'd4'], 'c1': ['a2', 'b3', 'e2', 'd3'], 'e6': ['c5', 'c7', 'd4', 'd8', 'g5', 'g7', 'f4', 'f8'], 'c7': ['a6', 'a8', 'b5', 'e6', 'e8', 'd5'], 'c6': ['a5', 'a7', 'b4', 'b8', 'e5', 'e7', 'd4', 'd8'], 'c5': ['a4', 'a6', 'b3', 'b7', 'e4', 'e6', 'd3', 'd7'], 'c4': ['a3', 'a5', 'b2', 'b6', 'e3', 'e5', 'd2', 'd6'], 'e7': ['c6', 'c8', 'd5', 'g6', 'g8', 'f5'], 'a8': ['c7', 'b6'], 'c8': ['a7', 'b6', 'e7', 'd6'], 'e8': ['c7', 'd6', 'g7', 'f6']}


def bfs1(g, s):
        # parent = {s: None}
        level = {s: 0}
        frontier = [s]
        ctr = 1
        while frontier:
                next = []
                for i in frontier:
                    for j in g[i]:
                        if j not in level:
                            # parent[j] = i
                            level[j] = ctr
                            next.append(j)
                frontier = next
                ctr += 1
        return level



    for i in range(int(raw_input())):
        x, y =  raw_input().split()
        print bfs1(d, x).get(y)
```

Comment: What is that supposed to do? What are the arguments (`g` and `s`)? What is the expexcted result?

Comment: are others' solutions implemented in python also?

Comment: `parent` seems useless - you only use it for `if j not in parent`, and `level` would work just as well there - but other than that, I don't see any obvious major inefficiencies.

Comment: @zvone The title pretty much says what it's supposed to do. Be a BFS, which is a well known algorithm.

Comment: This seems fine to me, if you want your code reviewed, might be better to ask at [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @amit BFS only means that it is not DFS. Having only that as specification, I would implement a generator taking only one argument. Nothing similar to this.

Comment: @PanLong yes others solution are also implemented in python

Comment: @zvone I have updated what g and  s is

Comment: @user2357112 `parent ` is useless for  most of  problems  but it is useful in some

Comment: This is a slightly weird way of creating a queue (with `frontier` and `next`). Why not just use a `deque`? I bet it would be faster, and it would also simplify the code.

Comment: Regarding `parent`, it's useful in some, but not this one, and if you're looking for more speed, dropping it will help.

Comment: @senderle but in this problem I have to append at most 8 elements to `next` this is not huge .Can this small number affect the runtime

Comment: It's not the number. It's the nesting of `for` loops. Iteration in Python is slow, and there's also overhead for every reassignment of `next`, `frontier`, etc. [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) is a more natural solution to the problem, and leads to simpler code here. Faster (probably) and simpler! A no-brainer IMO.

Comment: does the timing include file read and setup of the adjacency list? of so, please post the complete code. an option for bfs is to search from both sides at the same time.

Comment: I replaced frontier with a deque and got no change in speed. Does your timing have a breakdown for where it is slow (in BFS, not in BFS)? Are you pre-generating the graph, or computing the legal moves for the knight at the time you are visiting a specific square? If the later, do you remember them for later test cases?

Comment: Read zvone's answer. The basic problem is not efficiency. The problem is doing too much. You compute the knight's path to every square on the board, instead of stopping when you get the required answer.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem performance-wise seem to be the fact that this is performing a full graph search and returning the distances of all nodes compared to the root node.

That is much more than is needed for the problem at hand.

In the [specific chess problem you are trying to solve](http://www.spoj.com/problems/NAKANJ/) (find out how many jumps a knight has to make from A to B), this function will find out how many jumps a knigth needs to make from A to **every other square**.

So, it if input asks for the simplest A1-B3 (answer: 1), this function will also calculate A1-C8, A1-H7...

There are several options for solving that problem. I would get rid of the `level` variable entirely and replace writing to it with a yield. So instead of:

```
level[j] = ctr
```

do this:

```
yield j, ctr
```

Then the caller of this function can stop further execution as soon as the wanted result is reached.

### Furthermore

I would also rename all the variables, so that it is clear what they are. There is no way you can make meaningful code analysis if it is all cryptic.

Then, replace `parent = {}` with `seen = set()`, because you only use it to skip nodes which were already seen.

With those little changes, you get:

```
def bfs1(adjacency, root):
    seen = {root}
    frontier = [root]
    yield root, 0
    next_distance = 1
    while frontier:
        next_frontier = []
        for node in frontier:
            for next_node in adjacency[node]:
                if next_node in seen:
                    continue
                seen.add(next_node)
                yield next_node, next_distance
                next_frontier.append(next_node)
        frontier = next_frontier
        next_distance += 1
```

And then you need:

```
def get_distance_from_a_to_b(a, b, adjacency):
    for node, distance in bfs1(adjacency, a):
        if node == b:
            return distance
```

Answer (score 1):

There has been some advice to implement a nice bfs. In two dimensional problems you can save half the time by searching from both ends simultanously.

But when it comes to brute optimisation for timing you always go for lookup tables. In your case you have quite nice constraints: 64 positions to start and 64 positions to finish. that is a pretty small lookup table of 4096 integers. So use whatever inefficient algorithm in a helper program to fill that lookup table and print it out. paste that table into the source code of your competition code.

Comment: I can't do that due to memory limit

Comment: @johnsmith: what is the limit? you could use a char type for lookup. or even a half byte. that woud shrink the table to 4096/2048 chars. by rotation and mirroring you could also normalize the start position to 10 fields, again shrinking the table to 640/320 chars. on my system your adjacency table has a size of 3344.